Is there an equivalent to `toString()` in Google apps script
First time working with Google Apps script and I would like to convert an integer to a string, something like myText=myText.toString(10).
What is the simplest way to do this?

toString() is available. What's wrong with it?

You can add an empty string, like 10 + '' or ''+10 . There is a toString property but you can't use 10.toString() (Syntax error). There are a few workarounds, though.

@qrsngky  (10).toString()

@TheMaster yes, and there are other workarounds, including 10..toString()

Just found a simple answer using the "+" operator
myText = "Number is "    
myText = myText+ 10

